# К какой части речи относится слово "всё" и может ли оно быть подлежащим?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

К какой части речи относится *всё*?

> Пробежал ветер, заколыхал колосья и снова ВСЁ стихло, замерло...

Может ли *всё* быть подлежащим?

Answer (score 1):

Пробежал ветер, заколыхал колосья,  и снова ВСЁ стихло, замерло....

Вообще говоря, слово "весь" относится к группе определительных местоимений: весь день, всё время,  вся страна, все люди. В то же время возможен переход местоименного  прилагательного в местоименное существительное: все уехали, всё стихло, со всеми познакомился, и такое местоименное существительное может быть подлежащим или дополнением.

Поэтому "всё" в данном случае - это   **местоименное  существительное ср. рода,** которое является в предложении подлежащим.

[всё | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91)

Предложение сложное, перед союзом И ставится запятая.